# Link a spinner with radio group

Tags: android

I have a spinner and three radiobuttons in my activity.
The spinner show a list of town and the radiobuttons some countries.

So I would like than when I check one of the radiobutton, the spinner display an empty text and if I select one of the town in the spinner, all the radiobutton become uncheck.

I tried to do this:

```
        listener_region = new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            Log.d("main checked", String.valueOf(listeneron));
            if (listeneron) {
                listeneron = false;
                spinner_region.setSelection(0);
                listeneron = true;
            }
        }
    };

    listener_spinner_region = new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {
            Log.d("main spinner", String.valueOf(listeneron));
            if (listeneron) {
                listeneron = false;
                button_france.setChecked(false);
                button_espagne.setChecked(false);
                button_international.setChecked(false);
                listeneron = true;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    };


    group_localisation.setOnCheckedChangeListener(listener_region);
    spinner_region.setOnItemSelectedListener(listener_spinner_region);
```

With spinner_region.setSelection(0) corresponding to an empty text.

But I have to touch two times the radiobutton.

Any idea?